# AngularJS SPA Refresh page

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

While developing some SPA AngularJS Application I define the rooting with $routeProvider. Everythings works fine, but I get tired with clicking through the whole application to see particular changes I've done anytime I republish the application to the server. Is there a possibility to change this behaviour? I mean, when I hit refresh on my browser or use some tools for automatical refreshing (like LiveReload Server) is there a way to tell angularJS to not to navigate to the default page?

Regarding to the comments below, here is the routing content.

Below is the MainRoutingContent

```js
'use strict'

angular.module('MainModule')

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'webapp/modules/authentication/views/login.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })
        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegistrationController',
            templateUrl: 'webapp/modules/registration/views/register.html'
        })
        .when('/', {
         controller: 'HomeController',
         templateUrl: 'webapp/modules/home/views/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}]);
```

The single html page has the ng-view defined:

```html
<div>
   <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

And some additional for the RegistrationModule:

```js
angular.module('RegistrationModule')

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/register/user', {
            controller: 'UserRegistrationController',
            templateUrl: 'webapp/modules/registration/views/register-user.html'
        })
        .when('/register/company', {
            controller: 'CompanyRegistrationController',
            templateUrl: 'webapp/modules/registration/views/register-company.html'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  I assume, however, you *mean* to ask how you would accomplish this task.

Comment: the reason that you are having issues with reload can be many; without seeing your code, one can assume that your issue is with html5Mode, but it could be related to how your controllers are populating data.

Comment: Ok, I added the routing logic from my app

Comment: You should not go back to the default page when refreshing **by default**: when refreshing, the index.html loads, the app starts, the router looks for the current location, and it goes to the associated route. That should happen automatically. If it doesn't, you have screwed up something. It's hard to say what without a clear description of what happens when refreshing (URL before, URL after) and without your code (we don't even know if you're using html5 mode or not).

Comment: I'm not using the html5 mode. For example when I navigate to the following url: http://localhost:8080/app/#/register/user and then refresh the page I get redirected to http://localhost:8080/app/#/login.  http://localhost:8080/app/#/login is the start page when the user is not logged in. The index.html contains only the ng-view and the js and css srcs used.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that the server, when receiving a request for `/app/`, redirects to the index.html page, instead of serving it directly. Do you see that happen in the network tab of the browser dev tools?

Comment: I figured it out. I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it. I defined some run block in the main module of my application with the redirection to the /login page. Here is the code:

```js
angular.module("app", [...])

.run(['$location',
    function ($location) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }])
```

If someone will get such an issue with refreshing the page in the future, please look for some run block defined in your code.